# Can another pair of eyes check my php code to see why when someone submits something into the form, it gets displayed twice?

Tags: php, database, forms, mysqli

I'm learning how to make a form that displays what's submitted. When I submit information into the form, the info displays twice and I am not sure why. My code may have a lot of errors because i'm still a noob with this. I'm double checking everything to see why it is getting displayed twice and I just can't seem to find the problem.

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost","root", "", "hits");

if(!$mysqli){
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$db_selected = mysqli_select_db($mysqli, "hits"); 

if(!$db_selected){
    die('can not use' . "hits" . ': ' . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$hit = $_POST['hit'];
$amount = $_POST['amount'];
$category = $_POST['category'];

$result = mysqli_query($mysqli, "INSERT into hit (hit, amount, category) VALUES ('$hit', '$amount', '$category')");

if(!mysqli_query($mysqli, "INSERT into hit (hit, amount, category) VALUES ('$hit', '$amount', '$category')")){
    die('Error: ' . mysql_Error());
}

$data = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM hit");

while($row = $data->fetch_assoc()) {

 Print "<tr>"; 
 Print "<th>Hit:</th> <td>".$row['hit'] . "</td> "; 
 Print "<th>Amount:</th> <td>".$row['amount'] . " </td>"; 
 Print "<th>Category:</th> <td>".$row['category'] . "</td></tr> ";
 Print "<br><br/>"; 
Print "</table>";
 // array_sum
 } 

?>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Asking for a pair of eyes is a definitely a "too localized question" case. Anyway, a programmer should *run* the code, not *watch* it.

Comment: You're executing the `INSERT` query twice...  And your code is also VERY vulnerable, never ever insert values received from remote into the database without checking/sanitizing/cleaning!

Comment: you are inserting it twice so it is displying twice

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You run the query twice.

```
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli, "INSERT into hit (hit, amount, category) VALUES ('$hit', '$amount', '$category')");

if(!mysqli_query($mysqli, "INSERT into hit (hit, amount, category) VALUES ('$hit', '$amount', '$category')")){
    die('Error: ' . mysql_Error());
}
```

I think you mean:

```
if( ! $result ){
    die('Error: ' . mysql_Error());
}
```

I would change to using [PDO for databases though](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/).

Comment: it's not running twice! hi's just defining the variable not executing it

Comment: @Memolition from [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php): mysqli_query — **Performs** a query on the database - emphasis mine.

Comment: so if I say `$variable = 'Something';` and then `echo $variable;` it echo twice?

Comment: I know what `mysqli_query` does and how it works but hi is not calling the `VARIABLE` `$result` !

Comment: thanks! what Xeoncross said fixed it.. also.. sorry for the title of this question? oh geez you advanced coding people intimidate me ;) edit: about pdo.. ive been told to switch to that. i jsut havent yet. my code is all over the place right now.. as you can tell.

Answer (score -1):

try removing this line:

```
while($row = $data->fetch_assoc()) {

 Print "<tr>"; 
 Print "<th>Hit:</th> <td>".$row['hit'] . "</td> "; 
 Print "<th>Amount:</th> <td>".$row['amount'] . " </td>"; 
 Print "<th>Category:</th> <td>".$row['category'] . "</td></tr> ";
 Print "<br><br/>"; 
Print "</table>"; // Remove This
 // array_sum
 }
```

and put it outside the while statement

Comment: thanks for responding. i actually had it outside of the bracket at first and then put it inside because i thought that was the problem at first. it wasnt but i'll put it back outside.